# How to make my scala program quit and return to the REPL?

Tags: scala, case, read-eval-print-loop, quit

So I made this scala file and it works great when I load it into the REPL.  What I want to do though is when the user inputs "Q", it exits the program and returns to the REPL.  I already have readLine set up with a case match that says:

```
case "Q" =>
```

I just don't know what to put after it to make the program quit.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `System.exit(0)` *provided* you fork a new console / REPL. If you run via SBT, then `fork in console := true` will accomplish that. If you're launching a REPL from within your code and using `run` in instead of `console`, then you'd want `fork in run`.

If you want to run a stand-alone REPL, then start your program and eventually have it exit back to the REPL, then you'll need to simply stop your read loop and return out of the entry-point method you called to start it up.

Given how little code you included, it's hard to say much more than this.